# Introduction to OCR

Tags: ocr

Someone gave me a trove full of amazing information. It is 200MB .tiff images of scanned announcements that goes back until the 40's. I want to digitize this, but I have no knowledge whatsoever about OCR. Some of the early material is barely readable by a human, let alone a machine. It is also in Hebrew.

I'm looking for advice on how to approach this. A good suggestion about books, articles, code libraries or software (all of them should be available freely on the web). I'm proficient in C++ and Python and can pick up another language if it is needed.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you need it searchable? If not, leave it as it is, as it will probably be more useful that way. I've never seen _great_ OCR (though some come close) for English; I'd imagine the error rate would be much higher with scanned Hebrew.

Comment: If it's barely readable by a human, the chances that a machine can read it are slim.

Comment: The stuff from the early forties up until the sixties probably won't be readable by a machine but everything from at least the seventies until now should be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like a great task for Python, using an OCR library. A quick Google search turned up [pytesser](http://code.google.com/p/pytesser/):

> PyTesser is an Optical Character Recognition module for Python. It takes as input an image or image file and outputs a string.
>
> PyTesser uses the [Tesseract OCR engine](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/), converting images to an accepted format and calling the Tesseract executable as an external script. A Windows executable is provided along with the Python scripts. The scripts should work in other operating systems as well.
>
> ...
>
> ### Usage Example
>
> ```
> >>> from pytesser import *
> >>> image = Image.open('fnord.tif')  # Open image object using PIL
> >>> print image_to_string(image)     # Run tesseract.exe on image
> fnord
> >>> print image_file_to_string('fnord.tif')
> fnord
> ```

Comment: Does pytesser support Hebrew, though?

Comment: Good point - tesseract supports [a lot of languages](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list), but I don't see Hebrew. It looks like there's relatively little interest in/support for OCRing Hebrew.

Comment: I found hocr (http://hocr.berlios.de/) and qhocr (http://code.google.com/p/qhocr/) that might help. Though I'm looking for more information and direction - basically what are general OCR algorithms? If I supply the library the font that was used (or mock a similar one) will it benefit the algorithm?

Comment: @CamelCamelCamel looks like Hebrew support was added to Tesseract in 10/2012.